# How to get value from url while using Jquery script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".uni_type").click(function(){
        uni_type = this.id;
        location.href = "filter-colleges.php?uni_type="+uni_type;
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="uni_type" id="central university">Central University</li>
    <li class="uni_type" id="state university">State University</li>
    <li class="uni_type" id="private university">Private University</li>
    <li class="uni_type" id="deemed university">Deemed University</li>
    <li class="uni_type" id="open university">Open University</li>
    <li class="uni_type" id="autonomus">Autonomus Institute</li>
</ul>
```

filter-college.php

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    $uni_type = $_GET['id'];
    echo '<script>alert('.$uni_type.')</script>';
?>
```

In this code I want to get `uni_type` value from the URL but when I click on any list item I'm moved to next page (i.e *filter-colleges.php*) and given an alert to `$uni_type` on *filter-colleges.php* page, but no value is displayed in the alert box. How can I get value from URL or alert `$uni_type`?

Answer (score 3):

You're fetching the wrong information in your `$_GET`:

```
<?php
   include('conn.php');
   $uni_type = $_GET['uni_type'];
   echo '<script>alert('.$uni_type.')</script>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are getting wrong `id` of `<li>`.Use `$(this).attr('id')` to get 'id' attribute of `<li>`.  Follow it -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".uni_type").click(function(){
            var uni_type = $(this).attr('id');
            location.href = "filter-colleges.php?uni_type="+uni_type;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And also you have put wrong id (`$_GET['id']` instead of `$_GET['uni_type']`) in your php code. See it -

```
<?php
   include('conn.php');
   $uni_type = $_GET['uni_type'];
   echo '<script>alert('.$uni_type.')</script>';
?>
```

And dont keep space in `id`,`class` or other attribute of tag. For best practice. It can cause unwanted output.

Comment: `this.id` is going to be the same as attribute `id`.